# manipulating a Play controller parameter in a template

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my play app(java) I have a table with different columns, if the user clicks on the title of each column, the table will be sorted based on that column. each time user clicks on it, the sorting should change from "asc" to "desc" and vice versa.

I need a solution that does this: each time the user clicks on the link, `order` changes from "asc" to "desc" and vice versa. and then my Controller should be called.

```
<a href="@routes.Application.changeOrder(order)">test</a>
```

is it possible to write a scala function inside my template to do this? or how to do it with javascript?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti can you explain how? would be great. im not very comfortable with javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if-clause:

```
@if(order.equals("asc")){
  <a href='@routes.Application.changeOrder("desc")'>test</a>
} else{
  <a href='@routes.Application.changeOrder("asc")'>test</a>
}
```

Comment: you are actually right! I was thinking way too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Famous jquery plugin https://www.datatables.net/

[Here](http://feadro.com/play-framework-2-0-datatables-server-side-processing/) is a good How-To about using this plugin with Play for java